# Integrating an array of promises into an existing chain

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js

I've recently started using Sequelize and am trying to make a wrapper class for db access.

I call the connect method right after creating the object.

```
connect() {
    this.db = new Sequelize("sqlite:"+this.fp);
    return this.db.authenticate()
    .then(()=>console.log('Connected to:', this.fp))
    .then(()=>this.Card = this.db.define('card', { name: Sequelize.STRING }))
    .then(()=>this.Card.sync({ force: false }))
    .then(()=>this.Card.findAll())
    .then((cards) => 
        cards.map(c => c.get('name')).filter(c => (c && c != `''s`))
        .forEach(c => this.createCardTable(c))
    ).then(()=>console.log('this.cards:', this.cards))
    .then(()=>this.db)
    .catch(err=>console.log('Error connecting to database:', err));
}
```

The connect method calls the createCardTable from cards.map()

```
createCardTable(card) {
    const newTable = this.db.define(card,
        {entry: Sequelize.STRING, content: Sequelize.STRING},
        {freezeTableName: true});
    return newTable.sync({ force: false })
    .then(()=>this.cards[card] = newTable)
    .then(()=>console.log('created table:', card))
    .catch(err=>console.log('Error creating table:', err));
}
```

I have a feeling this is where the problem lies (console.log(this.cards) runs first and shows an empty list, before I see the confirmations of createCardTable)

```
.then((cards) => 
    cards.map(c => c.get('name')).filter(c => (c && c != `''s`))
    .forEach(c => this.createCardTable(c))
)
```

I think the calls to createCardTable are instantly resolving and causing the chain to continue prematurely. How should I return valid promises to continue the chain?

(I'd also love advice on how to clean my very ugly usage of promises)

Comment: Using Promises like that can get very confusing, really. What's the `console.log()` output you're getting?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Your code will look much better if you rewrite it using async/await and try/catch. Also, be aware that using `.catch()` supresses the error, so the following `.then()` will be executed whether the error happened or not - you function quite certainly doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: I'd love to know how to improve my promise usage. The code in the whole class feels terrible.The console.log(this.cards) initially has zero length, but when I open it in the console it has a note that the "value below was evaluated just now" and it does show the values I want

Comment: I was looking at await/async; if I make just connect() async and await the problematic part of the promise chain, would that fix the issue?

Comment: @Frax I reworded my post. Is my question clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the proper replacement to the troublesome link in the promise chain

New:

```
.then((cards) => 
    Promise.map(cards.map(c => c.get('name')).filter(c => (c && c != `''s`)),
    c => this.createCardTable(c))
)
```

(this is using bluebird promises)